# limit selection of custom taxonomies to one?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, jquery

I have a site with CPT (short for custom post type) "bagp_deals" and custom taxonomies
"ba_locations" and "ba_cats"
basically Its post type of "Deals" with "Location" and "Categories" as hierarchical taxonomies.
On the default edit screen i want to limit the selection to just one of each (one location and one category) and i'm trying to do that with JQuery,
i notice that the field custom taxonomy of ba_locations is named "tax_input[ba_locations][]" and so far i have this code:

```
jQuery("input[name=tax_input[ba_locations][]]").click(function () {
    selected = jQuery("input[name=tax_input[ba_locations][]]").filter(":checked").length;
    if (selected > 1){
        jQuery("input[name=tax_input[ba_locations][]]").each(function () {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
        });
        jQuery(this).attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

witch is suppose to limit the checkbox selection to one.
For some reason i can't get this to work.

**The Question**

So the question is why isn't this working ? 
or do you have a better solution to limit the selection to just one?

any help is appreciated.

### update:

this is the working code i used:

```
jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[ba_locations][]\"]").click(function () {
    selected = jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[ba_locations][]\"]").filter(":checked").length;
    if (selected > 1){
        jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[ba_locations][]\"]").each(function () {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
        });
        jQuery(this).attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking to do something similar to what was done here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-the-number-of-tags-added-to-a-post

Comment: I already figured it out, but thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of hacking it with jQuery, a more reliable solution would be to replace the meta box with your own, in PHP.

Anyway, the problem is most likely with the '[' and ']' characters in the selector:

```
"input[name=tax_input[ba_locations][]]"
```

could be rewritten as

```
"input[name=tax_input\\[ba_locations\\]\\[\\]]"
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: Thanks but nope that's not it' i have tried that already.
but i guess i have no other option then replacing the meta box with my own.

Answer (score 9):

i have a php solution for you:

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', 'htmlandcms_select_one_category');
function htmlandcms_select_one_category($args) {
    if (isset($args['taxonomy']) && $args['taxonomy'] == 'category_portfolio') {
        $args['walker'] = new Walker_Category_Radios;
        $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}

class Walker_Category_Radios extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {
        extract($args);
        if ( empty($taxonomy) )
            $taxonomy = 'category';

        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' )
            $name = 'post_category';
        else
            $name = 'tax_input['.$taxonomy.']';

        /** @var $popular_cats */
        $class = in_array( $category->term_id, $popular_cats ) ? ' class="popular-category"' : '';
        /** @var $selected_cats */
        $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" . '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="radio" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' . checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $selected_cats ), TRUE, FALSE ) . disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), FALSE, FALSE ) . ' /> ' . esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name )) . '</label>';
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! The only issue I'm seeing with this is that it still allows the user to pick multiple categories under "Most Popular." Anyway to extend this to that?

Comment: change metabox callback for "post_categories_meta_box", copy this function end change call of "wp_popular_terms_checklist" to your copy of this function where you change type checkbox to radio.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this, but I needed to do the same thing. I took your jQuery and added quotations for the name + escaped them. Seems to work fine for me, so thanks for the original jQuery :)

```
    jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[location][]\"]").click(function () {
        selected = jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[location][]\"]").filter(":checked").length;
        if (selected > 1){
            jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[location][]\"]").each(function () {
                    jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
            });
            jQuery(this).attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
```

My taxonomy input was called location and not ba_locations.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I threw in my functions, but I don't seem to be getting the results expected.

```
<?php add_action( 'admin_head', 'cat_sel' ); function cat_sel() {    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[rooms][]\"]").click(function () {
    selected = jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[rooms][]\"]").filter(":checked").length;
    if (selected > 1){
        jQuery("input[name=\"tax_input[rooms][]\"]").each(function () {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
        });
        jQuery(this).attr("checked", true);
    }
  });
});

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of [@sviryatko](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/32086/zviryatko)'s PHP solution:

```
namespace {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-walker-category-checklist.php');
    class Walker_Category_Radioset extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
        public function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
            $parent_output = '';
            parent::start_el($parent_output, $category, $depth, $args, $id);
            $output .= str_replace('checkbox', 'radio', $parent_output);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
add_filter(
    'wp_terms_checklist_args'
    , function($args) {
        if (isset($args['taxonomy']) && $args['taxonomy'] == YOUR_TAXONOMY) {
            $args['walker'] = new \Walker_Category_Radioset;
            $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
        }
        return $args;
    }
);
```